# Layout is broken, if no paragraph that stretches it exists

Tags: html, css

I am working on a simple website and developing its design with Sass and no other frameworks.

When I was developing the main page, I had the classic paragraph placeholder "Lorem Ipsum..".

The problem is that when this paragraph is missing, the width of the main layout is decreased and the main container falls onto the navigation menu.

***If I add a paragraph with more than 1 line, it fixes the layout (like stretching it) and makes it as when I was developing the homepage.***

This is the the basic layout:

```
<body>      
    <table id="max-container">
        <tr id="header">
            <td valign="top">
                    <header>
                            HeaderText
                    </header>
                    <section class='main-content' id="homepage">
                            <nav>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td> Home </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td> Contact </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </nav>
                            <article>
                                Some text here (Probably populated by some php script)
                            </article>
                    </section>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="bottom">
                <footer>
                    <div id="footer-text">
                        someTextHere
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
</body>
```

The basic layout, with the related CSS is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R4S57/8/).

This is the selection that appears with firefox inspector when I selected the max-container table:
[image: max-container-table selection]

and this is the selection when I select the body element:
[image: body]

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I'd suggest using divs instead of a table(ESPECIALLY for navigation). Tables are dated and difficult to work with.

Comment: Yup, tables are not for layouts. That's so 1999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually all your html was messed up.

I've wrote a clean html for the layout you desired.

Please check the updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R4S57/10/)

AND Please don't ever use table for layouts, common you have HTML5 for God's Sake!!

**HTML:**

```
<section class="main_container">
    <header>HeaderText</header>
    <section>    
        <aside>        
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </aside>
        <article>Some text here (Probably populated by some php script)</article>
    </section>
    <footer>someTextHere</footer>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
.main_container{background:#ddd;}
header, .main_container>section{padding-bottom:40px;}
aside{float:left;padding-right:20px;}
aside ul li{float:left;padding-right:10px;}
article{background:#e0eaf1;overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: This is how I had it (with the main-container) but I've changed it to table, because I wanted to make the page, take up the whole height of the viewport. 
Thank you for your suggestion, all seems to be working now :)

Comment: If you're okay using jQuery then you can write a cross browser function, so that the HTML would take the whole height of the viewport. If you wish to see it, I can write it down for you.

Please see a website that I build with the same effect : http://www.moneyfrog.in

Comment: Wow, great design at the site you posted, congrats :) Well, I simply need the main container to fill the whole height. This can be done by getting the current height and then what? :/ I would be interested to see this function, if that's not a problem for you :)

Comment: Thank you so much. By the way, here's the jQuery in the updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/R4S57/11/

The window.load function won't work in the fiddle as it comes from an iframe, try resizing the fiddle seperators or the resizers to see the effect.

Comment: Thanks for the jQuery script, I've integrated it but it didn't work :/ The think is that the main-container that contains the article and the aside-nav doens't reach to the footer. What I want to achieve, is that the main section of the site (width: 70%) that has all the content (header, main-container, footer) to have the same background color, which is different from the one that all the body has (hope I was clear :/ )

Comment: Yes obviously it wont work, the jquery library has to be loaded first to get the jQuery working, add this in your head tag above the body tag
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: No, the jQuery library is loaded just fine, since I am using it for setting the current page button at the navigation menu :/ (No errors show up at the console)

Comment: You are missing a semicolon at the end of document.ready function.
[here's updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PLcGp/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it still won't make the footer reach the bottom of the page :/ With chrome's inspector, when I have my mouse over the html tag, the equivalent selection at the website, is up until the footer, and not the whole page (regarding the height).

Comment: This is beacuse you have to position it.
Hope this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4S57/12/) helps

Comment: Thanks for your whole help :) But this didn't work as well :( I might ask a question later

Comment: Haha.. What are you trying to achieve..?

Comment: I would like the main website (of total width about 80%), to be taking up all the height of the viewport (that includes: header + main content + footer, as a group)